# Database for Moonlight

Tags: database, silverlight, mono, moonlight

I'm looking for a local database for Moonlight. I checked EffiProz Silverlight database and it seems to work fine with moonlight
Any other databases that work well with Moonlight?

Comment: This [moonlight](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/)? Also, why exactly do you need a database?

Answer (score 2):

Any database that work with Silverlight should work with Moonlight, if not it's a bug and should be reported to the Moonlight developers and it'll get fixed.

However testing that it actually works with Moonlight before deciding which one to choose is of course a good thing, Moonlight does of course have (as all software) bugs.

Answer (score 1):

[C# SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) is always an option... This fully-managed implementation (port) of SQLite is specifically meant to get around the need to P/Invoke native code and so is a perfect SQLite alternative for apps that require a fully managed database (such as Silverlight apps).

Comment: The link above is a link to a fully managed implementation of SQLite. It's not a binding to the C implementation, so it *can* be used in Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer with so few details but you can check [Firebird](http://www.mono-project.com/Firebird_Interbase)